# Color Thief does not detect right color

Tags: javascript, image, png, color-thief

I have this sample code that detects color using color-thief

https://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/k6Lumq8y/1/

when I run this, it detects the color which is different in the shade. The color which I am expecting ( RGB(0, 150, 209) ) is not being detected by color-thief. My code to detect color is as follow:

```
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
 const colorThief = new ColorThief();
 var detectedColors = colorThief.getPalette(img);
    console.log(detectedColors);
});
```

[image]

Comment: They apparently have a rounding issue, more fun with https://jsfiddle.net/xye6vaz3/ where they are able to find two shades of gray in a fully black image...

Comment: Right. I have exactly same problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you did the right thing by opening [the issue](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/issues/218) on their tracker, not sure what the SO community can offer you here. We could help you into making your own "color-detector" if you face an issue while doing so, but apart from that...

Comment: @Kaiido By posting here, I just wanted to ensure that there is no issue with code I have written to detect colors.